# How to run query from FQL?

Tags: php, facebook

Simple question..

How can I run a query from FQL?
Im using Graph API and PHP.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using [PHP Facebook API](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/):

```
$fql    =   "select name from user where uid=me()";
$param  =   array(
       'method'     => 'fql.query',
        'query'     => $fql,
      'callback'    => ''
);
$fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
```

Answer (score 1):

run fql query by fql.query function using facebook sdk

```
function  get_user_profile_details($user_facebook_id)
{
    $fql    =   "SELECT name,pic_square,pic,uid FROM user  where uid=".$user_facebook_id;
    $param  =   array(
        'method'    => 'fql.query',
        'query'     => $fql
    );
    $fqlResult   =   $this->facebook->api($param);
    return $fqlResult[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowdays you should migrate to and use the new GRAPH api:

```
$myQuery = "SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()";
$facebook->api("/fql?q=" . urlencode($myQuery) )
```