# how to use https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=

Tags: api, facebook

Hi i need to use https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query= to get user profile picture and other user information on PHP.

i know that https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query= return some json or XML.

but i don't know how to get json to use.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has built in json support. See [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) manual.

And if you are wondering how to run FQL from PHP - [it was just asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552474/how-to-run-query-from-fql).

Answer (score 2):

You can add a parameter format=json to get result in json format. So the url will be

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=fql&format=json&access_token=t
```

By default format is xml.

Answer (score 2):

The REST API [has been deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/616/). To make FQL queries you should use the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). To do so, just issue an `HTTP GET` request to `https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=` and provide your FQL statement as the value of the `q` parameter. For more info, check out the [FQL documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/). You can use the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3Dselect%20name%20from%20user%20where%20uid%20%3D%20me%28%29) to easily test FQL queries.